# How i can use Store() method to store image in database in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, store

when ever i fill submit form it give this massage BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74:
Method store does not exist.

**ArticleController**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $file = $request->file('attach');
    $filename = $file->store('local');
    $article = new Article;
    $article->title = $request->title;
    $article->body = $request->body;
    $article->attachment = $filename;
    $article->save();
    Session::flash('msg','Your data is saved now');
    return back();
}
```

**addarticle.blade.php**

```
{{Session::get('msg')}}
<form class="container col-lg-6" action="article" method="post" enctype ="multipart/form-data">
{{csrf_field()}}
<div class="form-group"></div>
    Title <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="title">
    Body <textarea name="body" id="" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="10">
</textarea>
    <input type="file" name="attach">
    <input type="submit">
</div>
```

**Route**

```
 Route::get('/', function () {
 return view('welcome');
 });
 Route::get('article','ArticleController@index');
 Route::post('article','ArticleController@store');
 Route::get('allarticle','ArticleController@show');
```

Comment: i changed but still same error

Comment: Btw, your HTML is invalid according to "Bootstrap standards".

Answer (score 1):

Change your opening form tag line to:

```
<form class="container col-lg-6" action="{{action('ArticleController@store')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

That will generate a url where the form will be submitted and will be less prone to errors. Because probably the error is that you are already on `/article` and `action="article"` generates url like `/article/article`.

---

*PS: Your HTML is not valid according to "bootstrap's standards".*

Comment: i change it but still same error i read from blog that store method is not available in laravel 5.2 .. is it right?

Comment: `store()` is a method in your controller. You are defining it. There's no way it is "not available in laravel 5.2".

Answer (score 0):

Change your form tag like this:-

```
<form class="container col-lg-6" action="{{ url('article') }}" method="post" enctype ="multipart/form-data">{{csrf_field()}}
```